# ionic zip - Adding data from multiple binary files to a single ZIP

Tags: c#, ionic-framework, zip

.NET 4.6.2

I read some (I know they are valid) files from a database and then try to combine them into a single ZIP file using the following function:

```
    public static byte[] CompressData(IList<ZipFileData> zipFileDatas)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[(int)zipFileDatas.Sum(z => z.Length)];

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            using (var zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                foreach (var zipFileData in zipFileDatas)
                    zip.AddEntry($"{zipFileData.FileName}.{zipFileData.FileType}", zipFileData.Data);

                zip.Save(ms);
            }

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The parameter is a collection of these:

```
public class ZipFileData
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }  // Eg: PDF, JPG, XSLX
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public long? Length { get; set; } // Length of the data
}
```

The function appears to work correctly, but later when I save the returned byte[] as "my.zip" and try and open it (from Windows 10), I get the error "The Compressed (zipped) Folder C:...\my.zip is invalid.

I'm trying to determine if this function (or some other code) is the cause of the issue.

Has anyone done something similar before or could verify that the function is (in)correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate a buffer too small:

```
var buffer = new byte[(int)zipFileDatas.Sum(z => z.Length)];
```

A non compressed zip file will be *slightly* larger that the sum of files inside: each zip entry has a header (sometimes a footer) and there is a "table of content" at the end of the zip file (the central directory).

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer)
```

will create a [non-resizable memory stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k(v=vs.110).aspx) a bit too small. Unfortunately for you, the last bytes you miss are the most important ones: That's where you find the offset of the central directory. Without it, you have a corrupted zip file.

To fix this, use a [resizable memory stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad966f9s(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var ms = new MemoryStream()
```

Comment: David - Thank you that worked a treat.  I do know about this, but I was always unsure what exactly happened if you didn't pre-allocate the space for a Memory Stream.